# Why QueryTrackingBehavior should not be NoTracking by default?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

While looking for a workaround for Entity Framework 7 RC1 problem (setting entities state as Added after ToList() for complex queries), I found db.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior property and set it to NoTracking. This fixed the problem.

I like this approach more because it allows me to manually control what's written to the database - I just need to mark all changed or added entities as Changed/Added.

Is there a drawback with this approach rather then a need to manually set state of modified entities as modified?

Comment: I have just done the same. I'm using EF core in a REST API which means the majority of the time I won't require tracking in anyway as the results will be returned to the client leaving me with a disconnected entity. I curious to hear others thoughts on this as well though.